# how to show icon android if user post listing from app android on website

Tags: javascript, android

i want to ask, how to show icon android if user post listing from app android (example : my user created listing from my app android, and , in the post listing show icon android)

and how to not show icon android if user posting from computer, laptop, or any device. (example : my user created listing from computer, laptop or any device other than "android", in the post listing icon android not show)

(maybe this script for website theme, not script android?, example for item.php to show this icon).

i search on google nothing, and what keyword for this?

this my icon android

and this link for example [this](http://www.olx.co.id/iklan/sarung-jok-mobil-press-jok-paten-ditangerang-76170243.html#pn_a977dcd0ffd2881f62ca8ef0c36d375c) look for bottom show text "Dipasang melalui Aplikasi Android"

thanks before

Comment: show icon Android on website, like example
this javascript or android script?

Comment: not answer, please help me